# Weights of $SU\left(5\right)$ representation

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, group-representations, lie-algebra

Consider the representation $\Lambda^2V$ of $su\left(5\right)$ where $V$ is the fundamental representation. How can I work out the Dynkin labels of its weights?

Are these the correct Dynkin labels for the weights of $V$: 
$$\left(1,0,0,0\right),\left(-1,1,0,0\right),\left(0,-1,1,0\right),\left(0,0,-1,1\right),\left(0,0,0,-1\right)$$

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: Related question by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/443748/2451

Comment: See chapter X of this [nice book](http://phyweb.lbl.gov/~rncahn/www/liealgebras/texall.pdf).

Comment: ... and the [Susyno package](http://renatofonseca.net/susyno/group_theory_tutorial.php) has a function "Weights" which does that automatically.

Comment: Ok, so does that mean we have $\left(0,0,0,1\right),\left(-2,1,0,1\right),\left(-1,-1,1,1\right),\left(-1,0,-1,2\right),\left(-1,0,0,0\right)$ for $\Lambda ^2 V$?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to recognize that a carrier space for the fully symmetric irrep $(N,0\ldots)$ of SU($m$) is spanned by the harmonic oscillator bosonic states of $N$ total excitation in $m$ dimension.  Denoting these by 
$\vert n_1,n_2,\ldots,n_m\rangle$, the weight of a state is
$(n_1-n_2, n_2-n_3\ldots,n_{m-1}-n_m)$.

Applying this to the fundamental of SU($5$), we have the $5$ basis states
$\vert 1,0,0,0,0\rangle$, $\vert 0,1,0,0,0\rangle$, $\vert 0,0,1,0,0\rangle$,
$\vert 0,0,0,1,0\rangle$ and $\vert 0,0,0,0,1\rangle$ with respective weights $(1,0,0,0),(-1,1,0,0),(0,-1,1,0),(0,0,-1,1)$ and $(0,0,0 -1)$.